# Is there a query support for the training status and the webhook url on the API of Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

Can i get the training status and the webhook url information with the API? I have checked the docs but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webhook URL is contained within `agent.json` in the ZIP file exported by [`projects.agent.export`](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent/export) in the V2 API.

If you make a call to [`projects.agent.train`](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent/train), you can call [`projects.operations.get`](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.operations/get) on its response in order to determine the current status of the training operation.

Comment: Thank you Dan Imrie-Situnayake.